# In skadate is it possible to switchoff caching?

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

Skadate is using smarty as template engine. It has a caching concept. I want to remove or temporarily switchoff the cache .Is it possible ?

Comment: You can't disable smarty cache. But you can enable DEV_MODE in ow_includes/config.php and smarty cache will be regenerate every time you refresh any page on your site.

Comment: Thank you . Now the cache is regenerating each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In skadate we can enable developer mode by  going to

> internals -> config.php

, there change DEV_MODE to true.See the code below

```
define('DEV_MODE', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two events are happened during skadate running one is caching, another is compiling. In normal situation system caches files and don't recompile request every request if the page already compiled. To avoid those two events you have to enable DEV_MODE to true. It disables caching and enable the system to recompile every request.